# Type 'System.Windows.Input.Cursor' cannot be serialized

Tags: c#, wpf, serialization, datacontractserializer

i want to serialize the datacontract
this is code datacontract

```
[Serializable]
//[DataContract(Name = "Shared", Namespace = "PJ")]
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(System.Windows.Media.MatrixTransform))]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownType(typeof(TPropHatchBrush))]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownType(typeof(System.Windows.Input.Cursor))]
public class TPropHatchBrush : TPropBrush, ICloneable
{
    [DataMember]
    public UInt32 uColor = 0xFFFE0606;
    [DataMember]
    public double Opacity = 1;
    [DataMember]
    public VisualBrush theBrush = new VisualBrush();
    [DataMember]
    public Grid grd = new Grid();
    [DataMember]
    public Path path = new Path();
    [DataMember]
    public SolidColorBrush blackBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
    //[DataMember]
    //public BitmapSource bmp = null;


    public Color Color
    {
        get
        {
            return TUtility.ColorFromUInt32(uColor);
        }
        set
        {
            uColor = TUtility.ColorToUInt32(value);
        }
    }
    //
    public TPropHatchBrush()
    {
        BrushType = BrushType.Hatch;

        path.Data = Geometry.Parse("M 0 0 L 15 15");
        blackBrush.Color = Colors.Black;
        path.Stroke = blackBrush;
        //path.StrokeThickness = 3;
        path.Fill = blackBrush;
        grd.Children.Add(path);
        theBrush.Viewport = new Rect(0, 0, 0.15, 0.15);
        theBrush.TileMode = TileMode.Tile;
        // Set Visual of VisualBrush
        //theBrush.Visual = grd;



    }
    override public Brush getBrush()
    {
        SolidColorBrush br = new SolidColorBrush(Color);
        br.Opacity = Opacity;
        return br;
    }
    /*override public bool FromArrayByte(byte[] val)
    {
        TPropHatchBrush tbrush = (TPropHatchBrush)CSerialization.dataContractDeserializer(val, typeof(TPropHatchBrush));
        return false;
    }*/
    public override bool FromArrayByte(byte[] val)
    {
        TPropHatchBrush tbrush = (TPropHatchBrush)CSerialization.dataContractDeserializer(val, typeof(TPropHatchBrush));
        return false;
    }
    public byte[] ToArrayByte()
    {
        //return CSerialization.saveSerializableObject(this);
        //CSerialization.dataContractSerializer(@"e:\test.xml", this);
        return CSerialization.dataContractSerializer(this);
    }
    override public void CopyFrom(TPropBrush to, TPropBrush from)
    {
        ((TPropHatchBrush)to).BrushType = ((TPropHatchBrush)from).BrushType;
        ((TPropHatchBrush)to).uColor = ((TPropHatchBrush)from).uColor;
        ((TPropHatchBrush)to).Opacity = ((TPropHatchBrush)from).Opacity;
    }
    public object Clone()
    {
        TPropHatchBrush to = new TPropHatchBrush();
        CopyFrom(to, this);
        return to;
    }
    override public bool FromBrush(Brush br)
    {
        SolidColorBrush sbr;
        try
        {
            sbr = (SolidColorBrush)br;
            Color = sbr.Color;
            Opacity = sbr.Opacity;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

when i serialize to this code

```
public static byte[] dataContractSerializer(object obj)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(obj.GetType());
        XmlDictionaryWriter binaryDictionaryWriter = XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateBinaryWriter(ms);
        ser.WriteObject(binaryDictionaryWriter, obj);
        binaryDictionaryWriter.Flush();
        byte[] data = ms.ToArray();
        return data;
    }
```

i have error and the error warning is

```
Additional information: Type 'System.Windows.Input.Cursor' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.  If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute.  See the Microsoft .NET Framework documentation for other supported types.
```

how to fix that? 
first i got a error MatrixTransform, so i use knowntype MatrixTransform and error in Input.Cursor, so i use knowntype Input.Cursor and still error.

edit

this is the result datacontract object before serialize

[image: images]

thanks

Comment: Your class doesn't seem to have a `System.Windows.Input.Cursor` property.  Also, the base class `TPropBrush` is never defined.  Can you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem in c#, trimming your class down to the simplest version that demonstrates the problem?  You may be able to use [Data Contract Surrogates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733064%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for `Cursor`.

Comment: yes i dont have a `System.Windows.Input.Cursor`. but another datacontract is work when i serialize without error `System.Windows.Input.Cursor`. , only this datacontract i got a error. @dbc

Comment: Check your other types used like TPropBrush.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot serialize a cursor. You can serialize cursor's name if it is one of standard type using ToString() method, and deserialize it with CursorConverter class.

```
     String cursorName = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("I:\\cursor.txt");
     CursorConverter cnv = new CursorConverter();
     Cursor c = (Cursor) cnv.ConvertFromString(cursorName);
```

If your cursor is present in a file, then you can get byte[] from that file, and serialize it. Then while deserializing, create a MemoryStream from byte[] using it's constructur and use Cursor's constructor to load Cursor from that memorystream.

```
    byte[] cursorBytes = ...
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(cursorBytes);
    Cursor c1 = new Cursor(ms);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce your problem with the following [minimal, complete, and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) test case:

```
[DataContract]
public class TPropHatchBrush : IDisposable
{
    System.Windows.Input.Cursor cursor;

    [DataMember]
    public System.Windows.Input.Cursor Cursor { get { return cursor; } set { cursor = value; } }

    #region IDisposable Members

    public void Dispose()
    {
        var oldCursor = Interlocked.Exchange(ref this.cursor, null);
        if (oldCursor != null)
            oldCursor.Dispose();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

The problem is that the [`Cursor`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Input/Cursor.cs) class is simply not serializable -- there's is no API to save one after loading it.  It is, however, possible to convert a cursor to its name, which is either a name from the [standard set of cursors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.cursors%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), or the filename from which the cursor was loaded, using [`CursorConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.cursorconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  You can take advantage of this fact to replace the `Cursor` during serialization with a [data contract surrogate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733064%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that stores the name of the cursor, rather than the cursor itself.  When deserializing, the surrogate would attempt to re-load the cursor from the name:

```
public class CursorDataSurrogate : IDataContractSurrogate
{
    [DataContract(Namespace = "")]
    class CursorName
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    #region IDataContractSurrogate Members

    public object GetCustomDataToExport(Type clrType, Type dataContractType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object GetCustomDataToExport(MemberInfo memberInfo, Type dataContractType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Type GetDataContractType(Type type)
    {
        if (type == typeof(System.Windows.Input.Cursor))
            return typeof(CursorName);
        return type;
    }

    public object GetDeserializedObject(object obj, Type targetType)
    {
        if (obj is CursorName)
        {
            try
            {
                return (System.Windows.Input.Cursor)TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(System.Windows.Input.Cursor)).ConvertFromInvariantString(((CursorName)obj).Name);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // ArgumentException or Win32Exception could be generated if file is missing or name is invalid.  Handle here, or pass on?
                throw;
            }
        }
        return obj;
    }

    public void GetKnownCustomDataTypes(Collection<Type> customDataTypes)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object GetObjectToSerialize(object obj, Type targetType)
    {
        if (obj is System.Windows.Input.Cursor)
        {
            return new CursorName { Name = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(System.Windows.Input.Cursor)).ConvertToInvariantString(obj) };
        }
        return obj;
    }

    public Type GetReferencedTypeOnImport(string typeName, string typeNamespace, object customData)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public System.CodeDom.CodeTypeDeclaration ProcessImportedType(System.CodeDom.CodeTypeDeclaration typeDeclaration, System.CodeDom.CodeCompileUnit compileUnit)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

And then, in your method `dataContractSerializer`, use it like:

```
        var ser = new DataContractSerializer(obj.GetType(), new Type[] { }, Int32.MaxValue, false, false, new CursorDataSurrogate());
```

The XML thereby produced looks like:

> ```
> <TPropHatchBrush xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Question32622276">
>     <Cursor xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Windows.Input">
>         <Name xmlns="">IBeam</Name>
>     </Cursor>
> </TPropHatchBrush>
> ```

Note that the method to load a cursor by name could throw an exception if the cursor does not exist - e.g. because the file from which it was loaded no longer exists.  You may need to modify the surrogate to handle this rather than just rethrowing the exception.